# mostrar una imagen de tipo blob en php,HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

como puedo mostrar una imagen de tipo blob desde php,html

- mostrar una imagen de tipo blob
- En html,php[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: <td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($photo); ?>'></td>

Comment: en ese pedaso de codigo estoy tratando de mostrar la imagen

Comment: Puedes validar si el data de tu imagen con base64 es correcta en este enlace: https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64decoder Avísanos cómo te va

Comment: @JheymanMejia en la base de datos mysqyog me guardar como imagen de tipo (binary/image)

Comment: pero al momento de mostrar la imagen no me muestrar muy raro